# How to create programmatically multiple URL alias of same taxonomy term?

Tags: 7, uri, path-aliases

I have category cars and I want to create its URL alias according to the region like if the user location is Australia than URL will `mysite/australia/cars` similar if the user location is USA than URL will be `mysite/usa/cars`.

Can you please anyone tell how can I achieve this kind of functionality?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You use pathauto module ?

Comment: Yes, i am using pathauto @berramou

Comment: Okay check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module:

You can use [`hook_pathauto_alias_alter`](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/pathauto/pathauto.api.php/function/hook_pathauto_alias_alter/7)  like the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_pathauto_alias_alter().
 */
function YourModuleName_pathauto_alias_alter(&$alias, array &$context) {
  // Change tags here by your term name
  if ($context['module'] == 'taxonomy_term' && isset($context['type']) && $context['type'] == 'tags'){
   // Get the current user the location for example australia
    $user_location = 'australia';
    // Change the alias to be
    $alias = $user_location. '/cars/[term:name]';
  }
}
```

Comment: It will change permanent alias or something else?

Comment: This hook fired on create and update of your taxomony terms

Comment: From the hook comment section  **Alter Pathauto-generated aliases before saving**

Comment: But, I have already multiple terms than how I will use it for this?

Comment: For already existing alias you should go to bulk generate *admin/config/search/path/update_bulk*  and select terms pathauto will regenerate them for you .

Comment: ok, got it. let me try it

Comment: Do the regenerating alias after you implements the hook and clear the cache